# rails options_from_collection_for_select the current selection value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select table that is generated using

view :

```
<select id = "car_type", name="car_type">
  <%= options_from_collection_for_select @cartype, 'id', 'name' %>      
<select>
```

and in controller I have this

> @cartype = Cartype.find(:all)

I need to get the current selection value, so I can generate a second select table based on the first option selection. I am aware that this can be done with observe_field, however, there is some problems with observe_field, so first I decided to use parameter passing.

Would appreciate for any hints

can anyone point out, how can I get the current selection value and pass the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [Rails documentation for options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select) the last parameter is the selected value and should be an interger. E.g.

```
options_from_collection_for_select(@people, 'id', 'name', 1)
```